# How do I inspect Vim variables?

Tags: variables, vim

In `.vimrc`, there are several lines that look like:

```
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType="<c-x><c-o>"
```

How do I inspect them inside Vim? Something to this effect:

```
:echom &g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType
```

But that command results in an error:

```
E113: Unknown option: SuperTabDefaultCompletionType
E15: Invalid expression: &g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType
```

How do I inspect these kinds of variables in Vim? Some plugins set some defaults which I need to inspect.

Comment: To clarify: The `&` prefix in Vim allows you to treat the options of `set` commands as variables.  This can be useful sometimes, especially in scripts.  E.g., the following two commands are equivalent: `set foldmethod=expr` and `let &foldmethod='expr'`.  The `&` simply allows you to access the "set command" option as a variable. See `:h let-&` for more.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

```
:echo g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType
```

works fine. It gives an error if the variable isn't defined.

Comment: Except that doesn't work for `%`. You have to use `:echo expand("%")`

Answer (score 29):

Like lucapette wrote you can use `:echo g:foo` to inspect a variable. You can also use `:let` to see *all* defined variables and their values.

Answer (score 9):

See if this helps: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/19.html. Should give you some insight on how vim variables work, and you can check out chapter 20 as well if you have any difficulties inspecting them due to scope issues.